# Can monsters take actions that aren't detailed in their stat blocks?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions

Me and my players got into an argument as to whether or not an Oni could take the Dodge action. This led me to question whether a monster can take normal actions other than the ones in its stat block. To me, at first, it seemed obvious that they could, but I am not a hundred percent sure.

Can monsters take actions that aren't detailed in their stat blocks?

Comment: This question is important.  We need canonical answer to this, because in many answers on this site, sometimes highly upvoted ones, I have seen the assumption that monsters can only do things detailed in their stat block, and cannot attack with any other weapon, use any item not detailed there etc. I agree that it looks simplistic and ill researched, but it is needed in a clean form inviting canonical answers, as a reference.

Comment: @Mołot The question linked by Someone_Evil is a canonical answer, but this is a useful duplicate as a search hit.

Comment: @AlexSash   I've marked your question as a duplicate because I think it is essentially the same as the other one. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why, and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Answer (score 26):

### Yes, the PHB actions are available to all creatures

The [Actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/introduction#Actions) section of the introduction of the *Monster Manual* (and the [corresponding part of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#Actions)) states:

> When a monster takes its action, it can choose from the options in the Actions section of its stat block or use one of the actions available to all creatures, such as the Dash or Hide action, as described in the *Player’s Handbook*.

The actions available to all includes the Dodge action. See [What are "the actions available to all creatures"?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/189130/52137) for more details, and [Why do we assume that PHB rules apply to monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/181459/52137) may be of use as well.